# Do I need to include all relationships in my class diagram?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, model

For example, I have managers who are responsible for contracts. These contracts belong to a department.
So what I have done is this:

**manager**(1) *belongs to a* **department**(1)

**department**(1) *contains* **contracts**(0..*)

In this situation, is it necessary to also include the following relation:

**manager**(1) *manipulates* **contracts**(0..*) to find for example who is the manager responsible for this contract?

But, I don't need to have this relationship to answer that question. Because I can find it by the first two relationships.

So what I wanted to know is if it is necessary to include all relationships in the diagram or if I feel that I don't need this particular relationship I can discard it?

Comment: What's your goal? Satisfy a requirement set by others, or communicate the design?

Comment: My goal is satisfy a requirement. So I wanted to know this so can I can reduce unnecessary relationships or attributes.

Comment: who is the diagram for? ask them

Comment: Keep the diagram as clear and simple as possible. Redundant information may cause confusion "reading" the diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First for the general case:
A relationship that follows implicitly from other relationships could be left out.

In your specific example, this is the case, because there is a one-to-one relationship between manager and department. Therefore if someone is a manager for a department, they (and only they) are the only manager responsible for a contract of that department.

If for some reason the relationship between department and manager changes, you will need to re-examine whether you can leave out the relationship between manager and contract.